# parallel quicksort boost::thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, quicksort

I wrote an in-place implementation of the quicksort algorithm and it performed beautifully (0.8ms for 1024 elements). I figured I could make it perform even faster if I implemented it on multiple threads so I tried using boost::thread and the list sorted perfectly but it took 1500 times longer than my sequential version (1539.3ms). I tried limiting the number of threads to various numbers but nothing seemed to make it as fast as the original version. Any reason why this seems to be the case? Has anybody successfully implemented a parallel in-place quicksort?

Comment: How often do you create threads ? How many threads are you using ? My bet : the cost to create the threads and synchronize them is bigger than the pay off.

Comment: I have a maximum number of threads, 4 for example and if the amount of running threads is less then 4 I open a new one each time the array gets split.

Comment: Here's an exercise to get a useful data point: take your multi-threaded code, but set the limit on the number of threads to 1.

Comment: One issue to consider: some computer architectures really don't like it when two different threads are modifying similarly-located memory.

Comment: One last comment -- trying to optimize a routine that takes 0.8ms of your program's run-time is a waste of effort (except as an intellectual exercise). Trying to optimize a routine that does this a million times would be useful, but you have an obvious source of parallelism there: set your threads to work on entirely different arrays.

Comment: @Hurkyl already did that its still slower than doing it sequentially (about 13ms)

Comment: @PgrAm: So, you are getting 15 time slowdown just from the overhead induced by the way you organized the program. The extra factor of 100 when multi-threaded is probably due to the threads actually competing for locks (or similar). To make this work on such a tiny dataset -- if its possible -- you'll have to find a way to organize the work to avoid dealing with parallelism as much as possible. e.g. change how you are creating threads, and producing/consuming work units. Or make it so that you switch to single-threaded versions whenever the lists are smaller than 100 elements or something.

Answer (score 3):

General pieces of advice:

- Don't parallelize small workloads, it won't work (just try and measure how long does the OS take to create a new thread, compare that to your 8 ms). You are underestimating that cost.

  - Each different thread should still have a sizeable workload, fall back to single thread otherwise.
- Don't lock *if possible*. If you lock, you just give the opportunity to your CPU to do nothing.
- Don't share the data on different threads. That is:

  - first don't access the same data for writing (never)
  - Don't access data that is "close" in memory (false sharing effect)
- Use a task library instead of threads ([boost.threadpool](http://threadpool.sourceforge.net/) the one I like, but there are others equally good).

  - Don't kill created threads, have them wait for more work
- Don't run more threads than you have processors (logical processors if you have hyperthreading or similar).
- Use CPU affinity to lock the threads on a given core (how depends on your OS).

EDIT: try with 1 million elements or something, because 1000 is *really* small. Then try drawing the curve of efficiency per threads vs size of the array.

Comment: the sequential one takes 2621.8 ms for 1000000 elements and the multithreaded version crashes after taking 4 to 5 seconds

Comment: @PgrAm: if it crashes, then it's buggy - that bug may or may not account for the wasted time.  Fix it, then tell us how fast/slow it is....